# PyPDF2's extract_text() returns gibberish, what do I do?

Tags: python, pdf, pypdf

I need to clip some pdfs based on the last word in their text bodies. While visually the pdfs are normal, when I run the `reader.pages[..].extract_text()` method, the text is semi-corrupt. Example screenshot and the returned string (not English):

returned: `భోపౄ /ఛఃగూ áఢ`, see how the `á` is not part of the string, and it replaced the next letter's diacritic.

[image]

Comment: PDF is **fundamentally not a format for storing text**. It is more like a set of instructions to an image editor, that include instructions to use the text-rendering tool. Anything that tries to extract text from a PDF needs to do a considerable amount of interpretation, and sometimes it guesses wrong. To debug the issue in any more detail than that would require a proper [mre] *including a minimal PDF* (and I can assure you that creating "a minimal PDF" for an issue like this is going to be very difficult).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel thank you for your answer. In case you have experience with documents, I want to ask if there is any format that I can go to starting from .docx, where the notion of a "page" is supported. I need to delete all but the first of the pages from the document, and pdf seemed like the only way to me. but clearly from what you have told me this is a dead end since it does not preserve text directly. what are my options? sorry if this isn't the right place to ask.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with .docx itself for your use case? what actually is the underlying problem you're trying to solve? You should probably start over and *ask about that directly*. For that matter - what should "page" mean? Are you expecting a document format that *explicitly tracks* what's on each page, or are you expecting it to just be a consequence of the physical page size vs. the typesetting?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I need to generate page-text pairs with randomly generated words from scratch as seen in my screenshot. The issue is that I need to know where to clip the text so that the paragraphs in the document that flow over into page 2 are not represented in the text. My approach was to first generate the documents, match the last word of the first page to my text, and clip it off there.

Comment: check the section [Missing Semantic Layer](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/extract-text.html#missing-semantic-layer) in the doc

Comment: PyPDF2 is deprecated. Use pypdf (I'm the maintainer of PyPDF2 and pypdf)